# Spring Boot and Mockito verify always true

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, mockito

I have a test in which I want to verify that a method was called with given parameters:

```
    @Autowired
    private Client client;

    @Autowired
    private OtherClient otherClient;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        client.push();

        Mockito.verify(otherClient).publishReset(
            Mockito.anyString(),
            Mockito.argThat(l -> l.size() == 3)
        );
    }
```

Problem is that `Mockito.verify` doesn't fail at all, I can replace `l -> l.size() == 3` with any other size match and given test will always pass. How is it even possible for verify to always pass whatever I pass to argThat?

Full example below:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener.class,
    ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    MockitoTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.class
})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ContextConfiguration(
    loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class,
    classes = {MyApp.class, IntegrationTestContext.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class FooIT {
    @Autowired
    private Client client;

    @Autowired
    private OtherClient otherClient;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        client.push();

        Mockito.verify(otherClient).publishReset(
            Mockito.anyString(),
            Mockito.argThat(l -> l.size() == 3)
        );
    }
}
```

And a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@MockBeans({
    @MockBean(OtherClient.class),
})
public class IntegrationTestContext {
}
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Is Spring interfering with mockito somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in garbage collector, I created a large list `l` that container a lot of objects (> 30k with many fields), when I reduced the size to e.g. 100 everything started to work correctly.

So basically: don't force mockito to work with objects that take too much memory (probably some kind of weak reference is used), e.g. reduce the size of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Mockito has problems spying on Spring proxies and final classes/methods. In some cases, this may help:

```
    Mockito.mock(SomeMockableType.class,AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo(someInstanceThatIsNotMockableOrSpyable));

    //
    // In your case:
    @Test
    public void test() {        
      OtherClient yourSpy = Mockito.mock(OtherClient.class,    
         AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo(otherClient));

      client.push();

      Mockito.verify(yourSpy).publishReset(
         Mockito.anyString(),
         Mockito.argThat(l -> l.size() == 3)
       );
    }
```

This has helped me with a similar problem and was inspired by this [Mockito-issue](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/529) on Github.